# Alerting on discrete application state in Kubernetes outside of liveness probe

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

My organization operates a fair number of Spring-boot microservices which commonly use two level of spring-boot-actuator style health-checks: one to inform the load balancers that the service is or isn't available (directly analogous to a liveness probe in Kubernetes), and a separate detailed health-check available over HTTP to allow more fine-grained alerting on the application being in some kind of suboptimal state.  Of course, we also record application metrics as a time series and monitor and alert on that, but this is a way to define per application what a basic assessment of "health" is and signal that investigation needs to take place.

For example, perhaps a data set the application relies on is stale, or a dependency is responding slowly.  These are conditions that need not take the instance of the service out of load balancing, but should be investigated and resolved.

As we're preparing to migrate many of these services into Kubernetes, we're not seeing a directly analogous convention for that "detailed health-check" pattern that doesn't affect the liveness probe or readiness probe.  Has anyone found a good pattern for handling this?  We're more than willing to work around adapting the interface to the clustering system, but would like to avoid needing to rework the entire logical approach of our monitoring.

Comment: It depends on what you expect to happen with the detailed monitoring. Do you want to prevent a microservice from servicing requests if it is in a suboptimal state? Do you want it to restart the application?

Comment: @Blokje5 Thanks for your response.  What I want to happen is that an alert is sent so that an engineer can investigate.

Comment: Yeah that is indeed not something covered by readiness/liveness probes. Those are really meant to take the application "offline" (By removing it from the loadbalancer) or to restart your application. Exposing the details as metrics and Prometheus + Alert manager is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, that's the impression I'd gotten; it just means a more significant amount of rework for our application monitoring.  But I guess good to get confirmation that is indeed a well-known solution.